# How would you write the model?

Tags: regression, self-study, mixed-model

Suppose you have SAS code as follows. This is from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/anovmix1.htm.

```
 PROC MIXED DATA=long;
  CLASS sub group trial;
  MODEL dv = group trial group*trial;
  REPEATED trial / SUBJECT=sub TYPE=CS;
run;
```

How would you write the model for this? Would it be:

`dv = group + trial  +group*trial + subj + error`? I am a little confused about how to write the mixed model in terms of a mathematical equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. But the key thing in mixed models is that there are two errors; such are more easily represented in matrix form

$Y = X\beta + z\gamma + \epsilon$

see the [SAS documentation for MIXED](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect022.htm), in particular the "details" section.